# Вектор в canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, вектор

У меня есть векторная картинка  с расширение eps.Возможно ли как то заместо обычной картинки вставить ту с расширением вектора? ведь вектор не должен падать в качестве от масштаба экрана

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


var im2a19 = new Image();

im2a19.src = "https://mobimg.b-cdn.net/pic/v2/gallery/111x185/abstrakciya-fon-40429.jpg";
im2a19.id = 'm124';

$(im2a19).on("click", function() {



});
document.body.appendChild(im2a19);
```

```css
#m124 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas>
```

Comment: eps не самый лучший формат для веба, лучше сконвертируйте в svg если возможно